# Words for "grave": tumba vs. sepultura

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, sinónimos

English has several words for burial places, many of which have specific, distinct meanings:

- grave
- tomb
- vault
- crypt
- mausoleum
- sepulcher

As far as I know, Spanish has at least two words for "grave":

- tumba
- sepultura

What types of burial places can each word refer to? Are both generic enough to cover any burial of a body or ashes in a plot in the ground, an underground crypt, an above-ground structure, etc.? Or are they more specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the words you mentioned have cognates in Spanish:

- [tumba](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=tumba&origen=RAE): place where a cadaver is buried.
- [cripta](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltObtenerHtml?origen=RAE&LEMA=cripta&SUPIND=0&CAREXT=10000&NEDIC=No#0_1): subterranean place used to bury the dead.
- [mausoleo](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=mausoleo&origen=RAE): a magnificent and sumptuous sepulchre.
- [sepulcro](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=sepulcro&origen=RAE): stone construction built off the ground as a resting place for one or more cadavers.

You already mentioned [sepultura](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltObtenerHtml?origen=RAE&LEMA=sepultura&SUPIND=0&CAREXT=10000&NEDIC=No#0_3) as a translation of *grave*: place where a cadaver is buried.

*Vault* could be translated as [bóveda](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=b%C3%B3veda&origen=RAE): a place where a cadaver is buried or a hole made on the ground to bury a cadaver.

There is also [panteón](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=pante%C3%B3n&origen=RAE) which is a cognate of *pantheon*. However, from my understanding this word has a more general meaning in Mexico and perhaps in Central America. In Colombia it is understood as a *funeral monument to bury several bodies*.

Comment: Thanks. Which of those terms would apply to a standard burial plot in the ground (no structure involved)?

Comment: Yes in at least the places I spent the most time in Mexico, *panteón* is the usual word for "cemetery".

Comment: @jrdioko, *fosa*.

Comment: Perhaps you could also add to the list the formal *cenotafio* (equivalent to *cenotaph*).

Comment: You could add "nicho" to the list, or is just used in Spain?

Comment: @Laura: I think `nicho` is mostly used in Spain. RAE has the following definition for `nicho`: `Concavidad formada para colocar algo; como las construcciones de los cementerios para colocar los cadáveres.` If I am presented with the above definition from RAE, I would have said that that's the definition for `fosa`.

Comment: @Icarius  "nichos" are not exactly fosas I'm adding a link: http://www.definicionabc.com/general/nicho.php anyway they're not exactly graves.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "tumba" is a bit more general, a "tumba" is a place where a cadaver lies (a tomb in english). "Sepultura" implies a bit more the idea than the cadaver was put there with any sort of ceremony, or at least someone explicitly put the body there. There is the verb "sepultar" that I would translate as the action of covering something with soil or another substance. 
I think the right translation of "sepultura" in english is "sepulcher".